# plotting pandas dataframe date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cluster-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe with 27 columns for electricity consumption, the first column represents the date and time for a two year duration and the other columns have a recorded hourly values for electricity consumption for 26 houses during two years.  What I'm doing is clustering using k-means.  Whenever I try to plot the date on the x-axis and the values of electricity consumption on the y-axis I have a problem which is x and y must have the same size.  I try to reshape and the problem is not being solved.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import datetime
data_consumption2 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Thesis\Tarek\Parent.xlsx", sheet_name="Consumption")
data_consumption2['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data_consumption2['Timestamp'], unit='s')
X=data_consumption2.iloc[: , 1:26].values
X=np.nan_to_num(X)
np.concatenate(X)
date=data_consumption2.iloc[: , 0].values
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(X)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(X)
C = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(X, R , s=40, c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), alpha=0.7)
plt.scatter(C[:,0] , C[:,1] , marker='*' , c='r', s=100)
```

I always get the same error message, X and Y must have save size, try to reshape your data.  When I tried to reshape the data it did not work because the date column's size is always smaller than the size of the rest columns.

Comment: Can you show part of your table?

Comment: Yes, how can the date column be shorter than the rest

Comment: I`ve added a photo in the question above

Comment: actually the date column is shorter because i`m consolidating all the rest of columns "which are 26" in one columns "which is vector of features" to pass it to the k-means algorithm

Comment: the date column is actually the same size "which is 16960 rows" but since I`m gathering the rest columns in one column, the date column is becoming shorter

Comment: is there anyway to cluster all the rest columns with respect to the same size of the date columns and not changing it or consolidating the columns?

Comment: This is not a correct way to do this. It is easier if you keep the data in "horizontal" format and when it is time to pass the features for your model act accordingly. Until then, having your data in this form is impractical and illogical

Comment: u mean I should not consolidate the data in 1D vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are essentially doing is a time series clustering of all households to find similar electricity usage pattern over time.

For that, each timestamp becomes a 'feature', while each household's usage becomes your data row. This will make it easier to apply sklearn clustering methods, which are typically in the form of `method.fit(x)` where `x` represents the features (pass the data as 2D array that has the shape of `(row, column)`). So your data needs to be transposed.

The refactored code is as such:

```
# what you have done 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Thesis\Tarek\Parent.xlsx", sheet_name="Consumption")
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')

# this is to fill all the NaN values with 0
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)

# transpose the dataframe accordingly
df = df.set_index('Timestamp').transpose()
df.rename(columns=lambda x : x.strftime('%D %H:%M:%S'), inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index':'house_no'}, inplace=True)
df.columns.rename(None, inplace=True)
df.head()
```

and you should see something like this (don't mind the data shown, I created some dummy data that is similar to yours).

[image]

Next, for clustering, this is what you can do:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(df.iloc[:,1:])
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(df.iloc[:,1:])
C = kmeans.cluster_centers_

# add a new column to your dataframe that contains the predicted clusters
df['cluster'] = y_kmeans
```

Finally, for plotting, you can produce the scatter chart you wanted using the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

color = ['red','green','blue']

plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    plt.scatter(x=row.index[1:-1], y=row.iloc[1:-1], c=color[row.iloc[-1]], marker='x', alpha=0.7, s=40)

for index, cluster_center in enumerate(kmeans.cluster_centers_):
    plt.scatter(x=df.columns[1:-1], y=cluster_center, c=color[index], marker='o', s=100)

plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.ylabel('Electricity Consumption')
plt.title(f'All Clusters - Scatter', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I would recommend plotting line plots for individual clusters, more visually appealing (to me):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))

for cluster_index in [0,1,2]:

    plt.subplot(3,1,cluster_index + 1)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.iloc[-1] == cluster_index:
            plt.plot(row.iloc[1:-1], c=color[row.iloc[-1]], linestyle='--', marker='x', alpha=0.5)

    plt.plot(kmeans.cluster_centers_[cluster_index], c = color[cluster_index], marker='o', alpha=1)

    plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
    plt.ylabel('Electricity Consumption')
    plt.title(f'Cluster {cluster_index}', fontsize=20)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: firstly, thats so nice of u thanks for helping me. Secondly, what if I wanna cluster in a specific duration and just plot the MON and the year?

Comment: Just resample your dataframe before transposing it : `df = df.resample('M', on='Timestamp').mean().transpose()`. Then, rename your column if you just want to preserve the month and year : `df.rename(columns=lambda x : x.strftime('%Y-%m'), inplace=True)`. The remaining steps are the same. Check out Pandas's documendation if you are not familiar with the method calls.

Comment: I really appreciate your helping, I`ll do

Comment: last question, why each cluster has more than a center? 
I want it to be one center for each cluster not more how can I do it?

Comment: Each of the timesteps is treated as a feature, thus 1 data has `N` features (depending on how many timesteps there are). Each cluster only has a single center, but each center consists of a value for every feature (thus a cluster center will have `N` values.

Comment: if you only want a single value for each center, what you are saying is, you only want 1 feature. In that case you have to aggregate the values across all the timesteps (e.g. taking mean or median), then you will end up with a single feature for each house (i.e. your cluster center will consist of 1 value only). If my answer helps, you can mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok ok now I get it, sure your answer helped a lot, I`ll try to figure out how to have just one center for each cluster. Thanks

Comment: plz can u tell me how what handles and labels should i put in the legend func?